# how to call all the files inside a folder using batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, saxon

```
java -Xss2048k -jar -DentityExpansionLimit=800000 "C:\testXsl\saxon9.jar" "C:\testXsl\In\" "C:\testXsl\XslFile\test.xsl" >"C:\testXsl\Out\out.xml" 2>"C:\testXsl\Logs\xsllog.xml"
```

how can i select all .xml files inside the `C:\testXsl\In\` folder thanks??

Comment: you can try to pass a wildcard `C:\testXsl\In\*.xml` as a parameter to the saxon jar; or if this is not recognized, try to iterate over all .xml files with a simple `for` loop

Comment: I already try C:\testXsl\In\*.xml and C:\testXsl\In\all.xml yesterday before i post here  and it send me an erron on my log that the source file not found in  C:\testXsl\In\*.xml and C:\testXsl\In\all.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XSLT you can use `collection('file:///C:/testXsl/In/?select=*.xml')` to read in all `.xml` files in that folder. See http://saxonica.com/documentation9.5/sourcedocs/collections.html for details on that syntax. That way a single stylesheet can process a collection of documents.

Answer (score 0):

This substitutes the name of one of the .xlm files in that directory each time through the loop

```
 for /f %%i in ('dir/b C:\testXsl\In\*.xlm') do(
    java -Xss2048k -jar -DentityExpansionLimit=800000 "C:\testXsl\saxon9.jar"
        %%i C:\testXsl\XslFile\test.xsl" >"C:\testXsl\Out\out.xml" 2>"C:\testXsl\Logs\xsllog.xml" )
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little whether you want to process all the files completely independently of each other. If you want to apply the same transformation to each file, to produce a corresponding output file, then from the command line both the -s and -o arguments can be directories. But a more flexible approach is to control the iteration from within the xslt code itself, by using the collection() function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solve..
 THanks To all

java -Xss2048k -jar -DentityExpansionLimit=800000 "C:\testXsl\saxon9.jar" "collection('C:/testXsl/In/?select=*.xml')" "C:\testXsl\XslFile\test.xsl" >"C:\testXsl\Out\out.xml" 2>"C:\testXsl\Logs\xsllog.xml"